# Why postgis st_overlaps reports Qgis' "avoid intersections" generated polygon as overlapping with others?

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgis-2.0

I am implementing a postgis trigger on polygon layer to check and reject newly created polygon if it overlaps others.

The problem shows when I digitize new polygons adjacent to others in Quantum GIS with option "avoid intersections" in `Settings -> Snapping Options`:

- Sometimes Postgis allow me to save and some time it doesn't with a
  message saying "overlapping polygon detected" (programmed into
  trigger).
- Sometimes Postgis doesn't allow saving the first time but
  when I save again (same unmodified geometry), it's done without any
  notice.

My trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_overlapping() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN
IF TG_OP = 'INSERT'
THEN
  IF
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM
       (SELECT id
        FROM polygon_layer AS t
        WHERE st_overlaps(NEW.geom, t.geom)) AS foo) > 0
  THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'OPERATION ABORTED: overlapping polygons!';
    RETURN NULL; 
  ELSE
    RETURN NEW;
  END IF;
ELSIF TG_OP = 'UPDATE'
THEN 
  IF
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM
       (SELECT id
        FROM polygon_layer AS t
        WHERE st_overlaps(NEW.geom, t.geom)
        AND (t.id <> OLD.id)) AS foo) > 0 
  THEN 
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'OPERATION ABORTED: overlapping polygons!';
    RETURN NULL; 
  ELSE RETURN NEW; 
  END IF; 
END IF; 
END; 
$BODY$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER check_overlapping_trg
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON polygon_layer
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_overlapping();
```

My software version: Qgis 1.8.0, Postgis 2.0

**Added June 24th, 2013:**

*Create table query:*

```
CREATE TABLE polygon_layer
(
  id serial primary key,
  geom geometry(MultiPolygon,3857)
);
CREATE INDEX polygon_layer_idx
  ON polygon_layer
  USING gist
  (geom);
```

*Test data:*

```
insert into polygon_layer (geom) select st_GeomFromEwkt('SRID=3857;MULTIPOLYGON(((11805973.8551485 1136129.8216546,11757217.3210366 1107981.71948687,11790391.87002 1102117.53153526,11823733.9672305 1116526.6790735,11801114.95656 1119207.45070852,11805973.8551485 1136129.8216546)))');
insert into polygon_layer (geom) select st_GeomFromEwkt('SRID=3857;MULTIPOLYGON(((11819880.3580052 1063581.43928182,11791397.1593831 1067602.59673435,11799483.2424957 1095075.79477947,11809995.0126011 1081844.19604541,11843504.6580388 1127249.76561359,11817272.092427 1129138.51033764,11832111.37859 1146852.90819468,11881203.0091563 1142329.10606058,11819880.3580052 1063581.43928182)))');
insert into polygon_layer (geom) select st_GeomFromEwkt('SRID=3857;MULTIPOLYGON(((11809995.0126011 1081844.19604541,11792995.1839403 1103242.5817722,11823733.9672305 1116526.6790735,11801114.95656 1119207.45070852,11804235.9486147 1130077.11269212,11843504.6580388 1127249.76561359,11809995.0126011 1081844.19604541)))');
```

*Trigger behavior:*

When run 3 insert queries, the first 2 will go smoothly but the 3rd will raise exception as defined in trigger function.

If I drop the trigger, insert all 3 polygons and check to find overlapping polygons with following query, I can not find anything:

```
select *
from polygon_layer as a
     inner join
     polygon_layer as b
     on st_overlaps(a.geom, b.geom)
where a.id < b.id
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what geom triggers the exception? And are you inserting geometries one at a time?

Comment: @JakubKania: Thanks for your response! I added information in the question.

Comment: Your second query searches for identical polygons. Use  the same function you used before.

Comment: @JakubKania: fixed my second query. I must have used the wrong query for all that time. After fixing my query, I discovered every once in a while, Qgis will generate a polygon that will overlap others, even with "Avoid intersections" turned on. I guess this is a rounding problem of newly generated polygons.

Comment: It's quite possible that's just a diffrence cause by diffrent method used by the two systems. You could try using ST_Buffer with a small negative value to trim around the edges.

Comment: @JakubKania: Thanks for your answer but that would defeat the whole system because I will use these polygon layers to further process other layers. I asked about this on Qgis mailing list and will report back the result: http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-user/2013-June/022847.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to a bug in the GEOS library and is being discussed [here](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/8174).

Until this bug is fixed in Qgis code, the user can avoid it by **only crosses boundaries on vertices** (digitize a snapped vertex on an existing one on boundary) while digitizing polygons.